# Gulp: Index.html not loading stylesheet

Tags: html, css, node.js, sass, gulp

**Problem**

`index.html` is not loading my `.css` file. I have a `gulp.js` file set up and I feel the folder directory could be the blocker here. My `.scss` files in `/src/scss` folder are correctly compiling to css within my `/build/css` folder.

**Desired outcome**

For index.html to load my css files and be viewable withing Firefox style editor.

**Folder directory**

[image]

**Basic HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <link type="text/css" href="../build/css/styles.css" />
        <title>Boiler plate</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Project name goes here</h1>
        <script src="./scripts/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Gulp.js file**

```
// const gulp = require('gulp');
const { series, src, dest, watch } = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

//Compile SCSS into CSS
function style() {
    // 1. Find SCSS file
    return (
        src('./src/scss/**/*.scss')
            // 2. Pass through sass compiler
            .pipe(sass())
            .on('error', sass.logError)
            // 3. Where do save compiled css
            .pipe(dest('./build/css'))
            // 4. Stream changes to all browsers
            .pipe(browserSync.stream())
    );
}

// Watch for changes in src directory and make updates
function watchFiles() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './src'
        }
    });
    watch('./src/scss/**/*.scss', style);
    watch('./src/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
    watch('./src/scripts/**/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

exports.style = style;
exports.watchFiles = watchFiles;
exports.default = series(style, watchFiles);
```

**Current errors**

Firefox console shows the followings error

```
The resource from “http://localhost:3000/build/css/styles.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)
```

When I remove the `rel="stylehseet"` and replace with `type="text/css"` the error dissappears. However, the same problem persists... No CSS file is loaded.

Comment: First, using a relative path ("../build/css/styles.css") isn't a good idea, because this is relative to the current page path. So even if it works for index.html it won't work for /blog/entries.html or something like that (if you have more pages). Second, how is your css file being served, by which server? If your server adds caching headers telling the browser to cache the file, your browser won't load the changed css because the filename hasn't changed. Check your browser dev tools, network tab, for the response headers for the css file.

Comment: this is strange, did you check if the file was loaded? Did you get an error on the browser console? does the file appear in the network tab?

Comment: What happens if you jsut change this part `href="../build/css/styles.css"` to `href="./build/css/styles.css"`?

Comment: @dirkgroten I checked the network. Status for css is 404. It just can't be found

Comment: @GabrielRodriguesSegalla I have updated for error in console. I get 404 in network tab.

Comment: @Mark No difference

Comment: I would try `href="././build/css/styles.css"` if index.html is inside of the src folder - it's a little hard to tell from the picture.

Comment: But when it says 404 not found, what URL is it trying to fetch? You should be able to see the absolute URL starting http://

Answer (score 2):

We don't use "type" attribute in "link" element. "type" attribute isn't necessary in HTML5.

Use "rel" attribute instead. "rel" stands for Relationship. It is used to tell the relationship between the linked file and HTML document. So if you modify your link tag as below, it should work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../build/css/styles.css" />
```